# TemplateDoesNotExist at / templates/home/hom_page.html

Tags: django, django-templates

i'm using django

here's my views code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'templates/Home/Home_page.html')
```

here's my urls code:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home"),
]
```

here's img:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a "templates" not "templates\Home" folder that has your html files, then just render it like this

```
return render(request, 'Home_page.html')
```